# how to print the text inputs from the loop in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

i want to print all user text inputs when i press the button. the problem when i press the button to print the inputs appear the error `TypeError: p() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. just to know the number to text inputs may vary from user to other

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

kv=Builder.load_string('''
ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        id:inputs
        cols:1
        row_force_default:True
        row_default_height:30
        size_hint_y:None
        height:self.minimum_height
''')

class Accounting(App):
    def build(self):return kv

    def on_start(self):
        self.return_list = [] #print this list
        w = Button(text='print all the text inputs',on_press=self.p)
        self.return_list.append(w)
        self.root.ids.inputs.add_widget(w)
        for i in range(5):
            w = TextInput()
            self.return_list.append(w)
            self.root.ids.inputs.add_widget(w)
        return self.return_list

    def p(self):print(self.return_list)#here

Accounting().run()
```

Comment: when you press button then `kivy`  runs it with argument `p(widget)` and you need `def p(self, widget)`

Comment: don't put all code in one line in `p()` and `build()` - it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click button then `Kivy` runs it with extra argument `p(widget)` so you can assign function to many buttons and you will see which button was clicked.

But it means you have to get this value in function

```
    def p(self, widget):
```

---

Minimal working code.

If you want text only from `TextInput` then removed `Button` from `return_list`.

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

kv = Builder.load_string('''
ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        id:inputs
        cols:1
        row_force_default:True
        row_default_height:30
        size_hint_y:None
        height:self.minimum_height
''')

class Accounting(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return kv

    def on_start(self):
        self.return_list = [] #print this list
        
        w = Button(text='print all the text inputs', on_press=self.p)
        self.return_list.append(w)
        self.root.ids.inputs.add_widget(w)
        
        for i in range(5):
            w = TextInput()
            self.return_list.append(w)
            self.root.ids.inputs.add_widget(w)

        return self.return_list

    def p(self, widget):
        print('widget:', widget)
        print('text  :', widget.text)
        
        for item in self.return_list:
            print(item.text)

Accounting().run()
```